# bochs enable internal debugger

Tags: debugging, bochs

I've problems in running Bochs with the debugger.
Currently I'm using Win8.1 x64, Bochs (latest version 2.6.6) is installed from the exe linked on the website, everything works but I can't find how to open the debugger.
Somewhere I read that I need to build it from the source with some option, but I'm not sure

So I tried to use a GUI debugger (peter-bochs). When I try to run it, it says that I miss pausebochs.exe and stopbochs.exe, however I've got bochsdbg.exe

How can I use that debugger?

Comment: Even if I unzip the jar, extract the two exes (three with ndisasm) and put them in the folder, it still don't work (same message)

Comment: In the console it writes: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program%20Files%20(x86)\Bochs-2.6.6\peter-bochs-debugger20140703 (The system cannot find the path specified)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I resolved:

1. Move to the folder which contains the bochs' jar file
2. Run this command on the console

   ```
   java -jar [bochs jar] [bochsdbg.exe path] -q -f [bochs configuration file]
   ```

On my computer, I ran this

```
java -jar peter-bochs-debugger20140703.jar bochsdbg.exe -q -f mybochconf.bxrc
```

Answer (score 0):

The jar should auto extract those two exe in the same folder. May be your path has special character, try to use a simpler path, e.g. c:\bochs